# Sending proactive bot framework messages to Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, botframework

If you use Resumption cookies to store conversation information between a user and your bot then you can initiate a proactive message. This works great for Facebook Messenger only as long as the user does not delete the conversation.

If they do then you get a 401 error and the user needs to once again initiate a conversation.

Is there any way to send a proactive message to a Facebook user even after they have deleted the conversation? This works fine in Skype for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible. In FBM when you delete a conversation with a bot, it can be interpreted as there is not any conversation in side of the FBM with the previous conversationId. Therefore, the bot can not instantiate a conversation up to user initiate a conversation with bot.

Comment: _“Unfortunately it is not possible”_ – that is very fortunate for users, who do not want to get spammed by bots after they already deleted a conversation.